# JavaFx как запретить распространение события MouseEvent

Tags: java, javafx

Создаю без рамочное окно. Для его перемещения к scene привязываю обработчики событий мыши MOUSE_PRESSED и MOUSE_DRAGGED.

```
    scene.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.ANY, event ->{
        if(event.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED) {
            xOffset = primaryStage.getX() - event.getScreenX();
            yOffset = primaryStage.getY() - event.getScreenY();
        }
        if(event.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED){
            primaryStage.setX(event.getScreenX() + xOffset);
            primaryStage.setY(event.getScreenY() + yOffset);
        }
    });
```

Затем устанавливаю кнопку которая обрабатывает событие MOUSE_CLICKED.
Но за эту кнопку возможно также перетаскивать окно, что не желательно.
Вопрос, как остановить распространение события MOUSE_DRAGGED с кнопки на scene?

Comment: if (event.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED) { event.consume(); return;} - такое не подойдет?

Comment: Не работает, перетаскивание за кнопку возможно.

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался. Необходимо для кнопки и scene указывать обработчики событий не addEventFilter(), а addEventHandler(), тогда событие MOUSE_DRAGGED мы сначала получим на кнопке. Затем с помощью метода consume() остановим дальнейшее распространение события.
В обработчик addEventHandler() кнопки необходимо включить:

```
if(event.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED){
    event.consume();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Я для перемещения использую следующую конструкцию:

```
 /**
 * Перемещение окна.
 *
 * @param event
 */
public void paneOnMouseDragged(final MouseEvent event) {

    stage.setX(event.getScreenX() + xOffset);
    stage.setY(event.getScreenY() + yOffset);
}

/**
 * Перемещение окна.
 *
 * @param event
 */
public void paneOnMousePressed(final MouseEvent event) {
    stage = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
    xOffset = stage.getX() - event.getScreenX();
    yOffset = stage.getY() - event.getScreenY();
}
```

Оба события привязаны в `fxml` `onMouseDragged="#paneOnMouseDragged" onMousePressed="#paneOnMousePressed"`. В методах используются поля класса.

Answer (score 0):

Для самопроверки можете поглядеть, как такая функциональность реализована внутри JavaFX. И ее даже можно использовать для недекорированных окон:

```
...
stage.show();

// За верхнюю часть высотой 22 можно перемещать окно:
com.sun.glass.ui.Window.getWindows().get(0).setUndecoratedMoveRectangle(22);

// За правый нижний квадрат 33х33 можно изменять размеры окна:
com.sun.glass.ui.Window.getWindows().get(0).setUndecoratedResizeRectangle(33);
```